# How can I click a flash object with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to click the video on this page `http://37.128.191.200/?640` using JavaScript but can't figure out how

```
document.getElementById('container').click()
```

does not work

Comment: If your intent is to make that video play programmatically, please say so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since manually clicking that video will make it play the video, I am guessing you want to do that.

You can run this on the page to do that:

```
jwplayer().play()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your JwPlayer object.

```
jwplayer('container').play()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `element.dispatchEvent` instead. So your code could be:

```
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);

document.getElementById('container').dispatchEvent(evt)
```

See more details in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

Comment: Will that work with flash? Looks like it just triggers javascript events.